# How to write in specific place inside a file using ant

Tags: java, ant

i am using java ant to deploy my application . I have a file app.php . I want to write some text in app.php while deploying in a specific location inside that file . This is my app.php :

```
'providers' => array(

                'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
                'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
                'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
        ),
```

I want to add a line at the end of this line :

```
'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
```

Please tell me how to do this .
Thanks.

Comment: You needn't had to post the entire file. Well, anyway, you can try reading the file through some `Stream` or `Reader` classes. Next you could store them in an array or `List` with _each line_ as an element. Now I guess you can locate the required `String` and add the line after that. **Hint:** `Vector` has a method : `addElementAt(int)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate this in more details ?

Answer (score 1):

you must use [`subString method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) like this:

at first store your file in a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) so after that you could do this:

```
  String s="your file";
  String firstPart=s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf(")")+1);
  String lastPart=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(")")+1);
  firstPart=firstPart+"\n"+"'Illuminate\\Workbench\\WorkbenchServiceProvider',";
  s=firstPart+lastPart;
```

---

How to read from file ?
Use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to *wrap* a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

```
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    try {

        String line;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  String str=sb.toString();
```

Comment: And then, how will this call be invoked by `ant` during deployment?

Comment: This I presume, is a more _generalised_ approach.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) or [Filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html) `ant` tasks.

Comment: Replace will , i think replace the token(string) with new one , i dont want to replace here , just want to add .

Comment: In that case replace `token` with `token + additional`.

Comment: "Replace" can "add" by replacing text used as a marker with itself and the additional text appended to the end. Or, your "token" can be a PHP comment noting that it will be replaced with something when deployed...